# Referenciar un objeto a otro sin que persista en base de datos con Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

estoy un poco desesperada.
Tengo una relación N - 1 en mi proyecto:

```
Mensaje
+id
+fecha
+mensaje
+estado (clave foránea a Estado)
```

```
Estado
+id
+descripcion
```

El caso es que tengo mis entitys de la siguiente manera

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "mensajes")
public class MensajesEntity {

    /** The id. */
    @Id
    @Column(length = 3)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    /** The message data. */
    @Column(length = 8000)
    private String mensaje;

    /** The start date. */
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date fecha;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="idEstado")
    private EstadoEntity idEstado;

}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name="estado")
public class EstadoEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(length = 3)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String descripcion;
}
```

¿Mi intención?
Poder guardar el mensaje con sólo el id del estado. Pero al pedirme el objeto completo, cuando guardo, guarda el mensaje pero también quiere guardar un Estado, el cuál no debería pues no es más que una colección.

Edit: Cuando lo lanzo me da este error:

```
Parameter value [0] did not match expected type [com.paquete.entity.EstadoEntity (n/a)]
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Todos los attrs de tu clase EstadoEntity, tienen que estar con @column, si quieres que algún atributo sea ignorado por Spring, utiliza @ Transient (se escribe todo junto, no me deja hacerlo en StackOverflow)

Comment: @EduBw Puedes escribir `@Transient`, formateando con comilla inversa `\``

Comment: Gracias, Me alegro que estés bien en estos tiempos difíciles :)

Comment: Cuando uso @Transient me da un error, lo he intentado :\